# How to use a serial bar-code scanner as a keyboard

Tags: windows, serial

I have a bar-code scanner connected through serial. I can get the readings (or data) through Putty.

I am looking to use the scanner as a keyboard, so that the scanner readings go directly to the text cursor (that is, notepad, Word, or a website).

More specifically, I need the readings to be displayed in a web application (browser). Thank you.

Comment: A barcode scanner usually requires a device called a "keyboard wedge" that the scanner plugs into which is then plugged into the computer that sends the scanned data to the keyboard input buffer of the computer. The keyboard wedge may also be implemented internally in the scanner or in a device driver or software program installed for the scanner. What does the manual for your scanner say?

Comment: @joeqwerty - great info, thank you! I will look into that.

Comment: -1 https://www.google.com/search?q=serial+to+keyboard+software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A barcode scanner usually requires a device called a "keyboard wedge" that the scanner plugs into which is then plugged into the computer that sends the scanned data to the keyboard input buffer of the computer. The keyboard wedge may also be implemented internally in the scanner or in a device driver or software program installed for the scanner. What does the manual for your scanner say?